# Add comments to code with regex in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I want to use regex to do two things:

1.Comment all the strings that  call the method .EnterText:

```
myField1.EnterText( a, 1000 );
myField2.EnterText( b, 3000 );
```

I have lots of those lines. How can I use regex to achieve something like this in Visual Studio:

```
//myField1.EnterText( a, 1000 );
//myField2.EnterText( b, 3000 );
```

2.After commenting those lines I want to copy them and change the calls in the following way:

```
myField1.Value = a;
```

So eventually I want to have something like this:

```
//myField1.EnterText( a, 1000 );
myField1.Value = a;
//myField2.EnterText( b, 3000 );
myField2.Value = b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Find what:

```
{{.*\.}EnterText\({[^,]+}.*}
```

Replace with

```
//\1\n\2Value = \3
```

In Visual Studio you have to use `{}` to create a capturing group, means: you can reuse the matched parts inside those brackets using backreferences. `\1` refers to the first opening bracket, `\2` to the second, ...

`[^,]+` is a negated character class that matches at least on character that is not a comma after the bracket of the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the trick to use curly brackets instead of normal brackets in Visual Studio!